# SQL Server 2017: sort_warning event fires when running a simple execution plan with no sorts and hash joins

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

sql gurus,
here is a script (fragment, object creation & data population postponed):

```
update #chart_estimate_
set [His seas data] = 1
from #chart_estimate_ ce
where exists (select top 1 r.[Investment_ID 1]
              from #reg r
              where  r.[Investment_ID 1] = ce.[Investment_ID 1] and
                     r.[Investment_ID 2] = ce.[Investment_ID 2] and
                     r.[his depth yy] = ce.[his depth yy] and
                     r.season_regr_wkn is not null)
```

here is it's actual execution plan, took by 'set statistics xml on/off' instruction: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1ono8AIt. No warnings, no sorts, no hash matches:

[image]

and here is XEvents session showing tempdb spills in my proc at line 6629 (this is where my code snippet stands):

[image]

this really makes me go nuts. XEvent contradicts actual plan! What is going on inside DB Engine?

Comment: There's not really much to go on here and an image of an execution plan is not much use, try adding the actual execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: @AaronBertrand `TOP 1` in a semi-join is *always* elided. It sometimes come back because of the row-goal, but it's not caused by the query text, in this case there is no `TOP` in the plan. What kind of sort is not shown in the query plan?

Comment: I suspect this is more likely to do with an index build/rebuild on the temp tables. How do you know that this plan is connected to that XEvent, are you comparing `plan_handle`?

Comment: Could be from STATMAN query that auto generates column statistics potentially?

Comment: @sTTu, plan shared, link attached

Comment: @Charlieface, XEvents’ sql_text identifies the proc

Comment: @Martin Smith, I didn’t knew statistics generate/update may cause spill to tempdb. How can I check it for sure?

Comment: It identifies the procedure, but is there anything else going on the procedure? How do you know it was that particular statement? You need to look at `offset` and `offset_end` also. And yes, statistics could spill, that is just one of many things it could be.

Comment: @Charlieface, I seek for statement based on line number. Is there a way to grant more memory for statistics creation/updating to avoid spill?

Comment: Not really. Switching on asynchronous statistics updates may be sensible, athough that won't help for temp tables